# "ln -sf" does not overwrite a symlink to a directory

Tags: linux, symlink, overwrite, ln

```
ln -sf
```

does not overwrite a given symlink to a directory.

See e.g.

```
% ls -ld program*        
drwxr-xr-x 22 b users 4096 Nov 25 14:33 program
drwxr-xr-x 22 b users 4096 Nov 25 14:29 program-201611181546
-rw-r--r--  1 b users    0 Nov 25 14:34 program-current
% ln -fs program-201611181546 program-current
% ls -ld program*                            
drwxr-xr-x 22 b users 4096 Nov 25 14:33 program
drwxr-xr-x 22 b users 4096 Nov 25 14:29 program-201611181546
lrwxrwxrwx  1 b users   18 Nov 25 14:34 program-current -> program-201611181546
% ln -fs program program-current 
% ls -ld program*               
drwxr-xr-x 22 b users 4096 Nov 25 14:33 program
drwxr-xr-x 22 b users 4096 Nov 25 14:34 program-201611181546
lrwxrwxrwx  1 b users   18 Nov 25 14:34 program-current -> program-201611181546
```

I would have expected

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 b users   18 Nov 25 14:34 program-current -> program
```

As workaround I can explicitly unlink.

```
% unlink program-current 
% ls -ld program*         
drwxr-xr-x 22 b users 4096 Nov 25 14:33 program
drwxr-xr-x 22 b users 4096 Nov 25 14:34 program-201611181546
% ln -fs program program-current
% ls -ld program*               
drwxr-xr-x 22 b users 4096 Nov 25 14:33 program
drwxr-xr-x 22 b users 4096 Nov 25 14:34 program-201611181546
lrwxrwxrwx  1 b users    5 Nov 25 14:35 program-current -> program
```

But I would prefer `ln` doing the job.

Is this possible? How?

Comment: Why downvote? To follow, or not to follow can be confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man ln`

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>   ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
>   ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
>   ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
>   ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)
>
> DESCRIPTION
>   In  the  1st form, create a link to TARGET with the name LINK_NAME.
>   In the 2nd form, create a link to TARGET in the current directory.
>   In the 3rd and 4th forms, create links to each TARGET in DIRECTORY.
> ```

You have the 3rd form, because your link is a link to a directory.

Comment: . . . and you can achieve the desired effect by forcing the 1st form, using the `-T` flag: `ln -Tfs emacs emacs-current`.

Comment: But the OP _doesn't_ have the 3rd form because his output is a `LINK_NAME` (i.e., 1st form) and not a `DIRECTORY`.

Comment: @ardnew: As 'program-current' is a symbolic link to a directory, it gets dereferenced (by default), so what `ln` "sees" is a directory as 2nd argument, which makes this a case of the 3rd form. To prevent `ln` from dereferencing, you need to add `-n` (or `--no-dereference`)

Comment: @Adrian if `ln` always dereferences, how would the first form ever apply? The only case it would ever apply is when `LINK_NAME` **cannot** be dereferenced, in which case `LINK_NAME` was a poor choice of a name

Comment: @ardnew The first form applies if LINK_NAME doesn't exist yet

Answer (score 1):

This little shell session leads to the answer.

Starting with files.

```
+4:25% touch f1 f2
touch f1 f2
+4:25% mkdir d1 d2
mkdir d1 d2
+4:25% ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:25 d1
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:25 d2
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f1
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f2
+4:25% ln -s f1 s0
ln -s f1 s0
+4:26% ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:25 d1
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:25 d2
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f1
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 b users    2 Jun 28 16:26 s0 -> f1
+4:26% ln -s f2 s0
ln: failed to create symbolic link 's0': File exists
(1)+4:26% ln -sf f2 s0
+4:26% ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:25 d1
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:25 d2
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f1
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 b users    2 Jun 28 16:26 s0 -> f2
```

Symlink directories.

```
+4:27% ln -sf d1 s0
+4:27% ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:25 d1
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:25 d2
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f1
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 b users    2 Jun 28 16:27 s0 -> d1
+4:27% ln -sf d2 s0
```

No warning message here!

```
+4:27% ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:27 d1
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:25 d2
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f1
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 b users    2 Jun 28 16:27 s0 -> d1
```

And finally there is

```
+4:27% ln -sfT d2 s0
+4:27% ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:27 d1
drwxr-xr-x 2 b users 4096 Jun 28 16:25 d2
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f1
-rw-r--r-- 1 b users    0 Jun 28 16:25 f2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 b users    2 Jun 28 16:27 s0 -> d2
+4:28%
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are use updating a symbolic link to a directory, you need to use `ln -snf`